# Ms Excel 2010 Comparing 2 columns and if the results match then compare another 2 and return the if they match

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

Ok this is a little confusing to explain, and even worse to word and search the internet for.

I have 4 columns with 700 rows in each, 2 of the columns are for IE8 that are GPO name, and Value, the other 2 are For IE10 that are GPO Name and Value.

I have managed to find a formula to compare the GPO names present in each column, and here is the formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$700,MATCH(B2,$A$1:$A$700,0),1),"*** NO ***")
```

So if the value is found in the other column it will show the name, otherwise it will display as *** NO ***.

So now, using this formula, i want to compare the values, but the problem is i want to compare them only if the name are present in both. Another problem is the Value might be "Enabled", but there are 400 other "Enabled" in the column, so it has to correlate to the value to the right of the GPO Name.

I cant attach a copy of the excel spreadsheet, but hopefully someone will have some idea of how this could be achieved.

Thanks in advance.

AntonSK

Comment: Can you not just nest another IF statement?

Comment: I have attempted to nest another IF statement, but I can't quite get the formula correct.

Comment: Don't use `IFERROR`, use `IF(ISERROR(...), TRUE, FALSE)`

Comment: OK Thanks, I will have a look at using IF(ISERROR(

Answer (score 0):

In your formula:
`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$700,MATCH(B2,$A$1:$A$700,0),1),"*** NO ***")`

MATCH() will return the **ROW NUMBER** from the range A1:A700, where the value matches B2. Lets say this is 32.

INNDEX() will then get the **VALUE** of the cell in row 32 of your speciffied range: A1:A700. letss say this is "GPO_Name_32".

You can use the result from the MATCH() to return a value from a different range, in the corresponding row (for example an adjacent column). Therefore your formulas would be (something like):
                  v - 
`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$700,MATCH(B2,$A$1:$A$700,0),1),"*** NO ***")`
and
`=IFERROR(INDEX($C$1:$C$700,MATCH(B2,$A$1:$A$700,0),1),"*** NO ***")`

Comment: Thank you for the response, this does kind of do what I want it to, but it doesn't compare the values to see if they match, any ideas?

Comment: please add an extract of some example data - showing columns you are using, so I can give a better answer...